# How to send information to the Remote-Control (lock screen) in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, lockscreen, remote-control

i'm currently having issues changing track information at the lock screen.  I have managed to get playing/pausing from the lock screen, and everything works fine and dandy, but I'm completely lost on how to send the *"currently playing"* information over to it.

I am using an **AVPlayer** to play streaming audio from the internet.  Does anyone know how to set the artist/track name at the lock screen? Perhaps by sending over the AVPlayerItem?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New in iOS 5, `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`.. Let's you send information to the lock screen such as artist info, song info, etc.

[Here is the documentation on it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)